# Strange neighbourhood in topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ from $X$.

I am wondering if $x-y$ could be far from $\bar x-\bar y$ even thought $x$ is in the neighbourhood of $\bar x$ and $y$ in the neighbourhood of $\bar y$ such that.

I can not imagine such a neighbourhood. First I think at a pair of neighbourhoods: one very large and one very small, but I did not find an explicit example.

Comment: use $X$ as a neighborhood, you could take $x$ and $y$ as far apart as you wish. What exactly you are asking, the term "neighborhood" is not very specific, what kind of neighborhood, how small, how big? Are you asking if you could pick some $x,y$ or that $x-y$ should be far from $\bar x-\bar y$ for every $x,y$ in some "suitable" neighborhoods: The latter would be impossible (as one could take in particular $x=\bar x$ and $y=\bar y$). And, what did you try?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what it is you're asking here, but I think what you're trying to say boils down to asking whether subtraction is a continuous function from $X \times X$ to $X$, under a given topology. Certainly, there will be plenty of topologies where subtraction will not be continuous, but such topologies tend not to be used in the context of studying normed linear spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A normed space (in the topology induced by the metric from the norm, so "closeness"  is measured by the norm) $X$ has the property that the addition function $+: X \times X \to X$ and the inversion function $-: X \to X$ are both continuous, and this implies easily that $(x,y) \to x-y$ is also continuous.
(this is genral theory.)

Or concretely:

$\|(x'-y')\| = \|(x'-x) + (x-y) + (y-y')\|\le \|x'-x\| + \|x-y\| + \|y-y'\|$, so

$$ \|(x'-y')\| - \|x-y\|  \le \|x'-x\| + \|y-y'\|$$

(and doing the reverse order on the left too even gives:

$$ \left|\|(x'-y')\| - \|x-y\|\right|  \le \|x'-x\| + \|y-y'\|$$

which shows that by choosing $x$ and $x'$ close and $y$ and $y'$ as well, we can make $x-y$ as close as we like to $x'-y'$.